# Server Not Found but Wifi is Connected

Tags: networking, 16.04, internet, dns, asus

I have installed ubuntu 16.04LTS on my Asus X555LAB laptop recently. Even though wifi is connected, internet is not working and I am not able to open web pages. Using command line, I tried to ping several websites, but it says 'host not found'. I read some questions here and found that there might be some problem with DNS server settings. I am not sure how to resolve this issue. can anyone help?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a "default" route set up. Read `man ip;man ip-route`, do `ip route` to check, and maybe `ip route add default to <routerIP> via eth0` (replace `eth0`)

Comment: Tried doing it, doesn't work. ethernet works fine though!

Comment: You could share information about your system, cut-and-paste what you've tried and how it fails. First read http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask. We need to see `ifconfig`, `ip route`, `cat /etc/resiolv.conf`, `uname -a`, `ping 8.8.8.8`. What do you mean by "connected", "unable to open", "tried to ping several websites", "read some questions", "tried doing it". The system often issues error messages that, while clear to experts, are reported as "but it says 'host not found'" by learners. Please Edit your original question to add this info, properly formatted.